# Undefined reference to function in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I have this code here in a header file and source files. Here are little snippets of the code. This is from the `.cpp` file.

```
int sample(Cdf* cdf)  
{
    //double RandomUniform();
    double r = RandomUniform(); //code that is causing the error
    for (int j = 0; j < cdf->n; j++)
    if (r < cdf->vals[j])
    return cdf->ids[j];
    // return 0;
}
```

This is from the `.c` file:

```
double RandomUniform(void)
{
    double uni;

    /* Make sure the initialisation routine has been called */
    if (!test) 
    RandomInitialise(1802,9373);

    uni = u[i97-1] - u[j97-1];
    if (uni <= 0.0)
    uni++;
    u[i97-1] = uni;
    i97--;

    // ...
}
```

And this is from my header file

```
void   RandomInitialise(int,int);
double RandomUniform();
double RandomGaussian(double,double);
int    RandomInt(int,int);
double RandomDouble(double,double);
```

I have used `#include "headerfile.h"` in the `.cpp` file and then I compiled the code. As you can see from the snippets, I am basically calling the function `RandomUniform()` that is in the `.cpp` file then defining it in the header file.

Problem is, whenever I build the program, I get an *"undefined reference to function"* error.
Here is the error I am getting

```
       In function 'Z6sampleP3Cdf':
       undefined reference to 'RandomUniform()'
```

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: What is `Cdf`? Where is it declared?

Comment: `RandomUniform()` != `RandomUniform(void)`, without any parameters it actually means `RandomUniform(...)`, a function that takes any number of parameters.

Comment: the answer below is fine but whats cdf.

Comment: @emil no, I dont think so .. a() == a(void)

Comment: @user2035796 How are you linking the C project to the C++ project? Please describe this process. If you don't know what I'm talking about, I suggest reading [The build process of Code::Blocks: Using project dependencies](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=The_build_process_of_Code%3a%3aBlocks#Using_project_dependencies)

Comment: The files are in the same project not different projects

Comment: And you include the C source file containing the `RandomUniform` function in the project? In other words, you _link_ with the correct files?

Comment: yes I have done the #include thing

Comment: this feels like a quiz show to me :D

Comment: the error occurs just after int(Cdf* cdf), in the function RandomUniform()

Comment: And how about the _linking_? The error is a _linker_ error meaning that the linker can't find the definition of the `RandomUniform` function. For the project to be complete, you need to compile _all_ source files to object files, then link _all_ object files into the final executable. _And_ if parts are in a C file you need the solution provided in my answer as well.

Comment: OK is there information on linking in the codeblocks documentation? I'm going to have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that C++ *mangles* its function names. So a function named `sample` in C++ will not be named the same in C.

And the oposite of course, a function like `void RandomInitialise(int,int)` in C will not be simply named `RandomInitialise` in C++.

You have to use `extern "C"` for your function implemented in C, or the C++ compiler will create mangled names for your C functions.

So you have to change your header file containing these C-only functions as:

```
extern "C" void   RandomInitialise(int,int);
extern "C" double RandomUniform(void);
extern "C" double RandomGaussian(double,double);
extern "C" int    RandomInt(int,int);
extern "C" double RandomDouble(double,double);
```

Of course this means you can't use the same header file from a pure C project, as `extern "C"` is not valid in a pure C compiler. But you can use the preprocessor to help with that:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void   RandomInitialise(int,int);
double RandomUniform(void);
double RandomGaussian(double,double);
int    RandomInt(int,int);
double RandomDouble(double,double);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: It's saying delaration of C function void sample() conflicts with previous declaration

Comment: i had already declared cdf elsewhere. The error actually lies with the function RandomUniform()

Comment: @user2035796 Then I suggest you edit your question to include the _actual_ error. And the code that causes that specific error.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't add your file to **debug** and **release** at file creation! Then that would be the problem!

The cpp files need to be linked and added! If not within debug and|or release! The linker will not find them!

### How to add them to debug or release

If they are already created! In the file explorer left! right click! And choose properties!
Within properties choose **build**! You'll find where to add debug and release!

[image]
[image]

### Note about extern "C"

Adding extern "C" is not necessary! And i confirm that! The linker link without problem!

Still check this answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455385/7668448

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15141021/7668448

Answer (score -4):

right click here then "add files " then choose the .h & .c files you want to editing their file pass then press ok.

[image: click here to see where to press]