# Using static class in c++

Tags: c++, file, compilation, header

I have some simple hypothetical static class in C++:

```
#ifndef __STAT_H_
#define __STAT_H_

class Stat {

 private:
  static vector<int> v;

 public:

  static void add_num(int num);
  static void clear_nums();
  static void get_count();
};

#endif
```

And the ccp file is so:

```
#include "Stat.h"

vector<int> v;


void Stat::add_num(int num) {
  v.push_back(num);
}

void Stat::clear_nums() {
  v.clear();
}

int Stat::get_num_count() {
  return v.size();
}
```

Now when I include in main.cpp file "Stat.h" and try to use some static method:

```
Stat::add_num(8);
```

the error during compilation is

undefined reference to 'Stat::add_num(int)'

What can be the problem in this case? Thank you.

EDIT: sorry about addresses vector, it should be v there

Comment: Most likely one of these (I'm looking at you, didn't link implementation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix. You also might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: You should explain what compilation command you are using, and what compiler you have.

Comment: command is: g++ main.cpp

Comment: Note: Your include guard is not valid according to the standard. All names beginning with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved by the implementation in the global namespace. (And as it is a macro, that is included) Names with double underscores are disallowed in all contexts. But that is unrelated to your question.

Comment: This is unrelated to the error, but there is no concept of static classes in C++.

Comment: `static void get_count();` in your header is inconsistent with the declaration in your `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have not included stat.cpp in compilation. So your linker cannot find an implementation for the static methods.

Comment: +1. I would additionally note that the declaration of `v` is wrong. It declares a vector `v`, not `Stat::v`.

Comment: I included stat.h into main.cpp

Comment: @Sergey: But you didn't tell the compiler about `stat.cpp` -- which is where `Stat::add_num` is defined. So the compiler (or rather, in this case the linker) is perfectly okay in saying "I don't know where to find this definition".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files

Comment: if I change stat.h to stat.cpp in include directive, it's the same error

Comment: You wouldn't change the include, you need to pass the cpp to the compiler itself. See the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link Stat.o in g++ command, say:

```
g++ -c -o Stat.o Stat.cpp
g++ -o Stat main.cpp Stat.o
```

I guess in your Stat.cpp:

```
vector<int> v;
```

should be:

```
vector<int> Stat::v;
```

There is no compile error if you define local v in Stat.cpp but I guess you intent to use `Stat::v`

Comment: This is also an error; but it is not the one the user is having a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your program, just for reference sake.

*Stat.h*

```
#ifndef STAT_H
#define STAT_H

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class Stat
{
 public:
  static void add_num(int num);
  static void clear_nums();
  static int get_count();

 private:
  static vector<int> v;
};

#endif
```

*Stat.cpp*

```
#include "Stat.h"

vector<int> Stat::v;

void Stat::add_num(int num) { v.push_back(num); }

void Stat::clear_nums() { v.clear(); }

int Stat::get_count() { return v.size(); }
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "Stat.h"

int main()
{
  Stat s;
  s.add_num(8);
}
```

*Makefile*

```
CC = g++
OBJS = Stat.o
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)

all: build clean

build: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) main.cpp $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o stat

Stat.o: Stat.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Stat.cpp

clean:
        -rm -f *.o
```