# C++ makefile on Linux with Multiple *.cpp files

Tags: c++, linux, file, makefile

I'm trying to make a makefile with multiple files. Can someone help me?
The files I have are file1.cpp, file2.h and main.cpp

file1.cpp contains my functions.
file2.h contains the declaration of my functions.

main.cpp [includes file2.h in the code]
file1.cpp [includes file2.h in the code]

i did

```
all: main
gcc -g -Wall -o main main.cpp
```

but it gives me tons of bugs when i try to compile. my codes works perfectly fine on eclipse.

Comment: Best answer is right here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you'll need to compile all .cpp files that you use (i assume they are not included somewhere).
That way the compiler will know that file1.cpp and main.cpp are used together.
Also I would suggest using g++ instead of gcc, because g++ is the specific c++ compiler while gcc supports C and C++.

Try using:

```
g++ -g -Wall -o main main.cpp file1.cpp
```

Also I would recommend to use Makefile variables like this:

```
SOURCES = main.cpp file1.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -o main $(SOURCES)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks it helps a lot. turned out i can just drag my eclipse makefile over as well XD

Answer (score 1):

> but it gives me tons of bugs when i try to compile. my codes works perfectly fine on eclipse.

`gcc` is not a C++ compiler.  Use `g++` instead.

Your `Makefile` should look like so, it can leverage [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

```
all: main

CXXFLAGS+=-g -Wall
LDLIBS+=-lstdc++
main: file1.o main.o
```

Comment: gcc is a C++ compiler. g++ uses gcc, but just in a way that it treats all files as C++ files (including *.c files)