# Understanding how to compile and correctly link multiple c++ files

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, g++

I want to write a basic program that involves multiple c++ files, and then compile the program from Ubuntu terminal with g++.

## main.cpp

```
#include "other.cpp"


int main()
{
     return test();
}
```

## other.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int test()
{

     cout<<"Hello" << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

...and then I run

```
g++ main.cpp other.cpp
```

Firstly, this does not work. I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccXYALau.o: In function `test()':
other.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `test()'
/tmp/ccCIj4co.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Even though I am clearly not defining test() twice? (question 1)

Secondly, I had to put

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

in other.cpp, instead of what would make more sense, main.cpp. This is because for some reason, even when I put the iostream include and the std namespacing at the top of main.cpp, other.cpp did not recognise iostream commands (cout, endl). I thought #include statements just put the c++ file contents where the #include statement is. What is the correct thing to do, and why does this not work? (question 2)

Finally, in general if my project gets more complex with more files, how does compiling all of them and linking them work (shouldn't all the includes be in main.cpp) and what is the process to compile them?  (question 3)

Comment: Use header files.

Comment: I thought there was no actual difference between .cpp and .h. Or does that really just regard the fact they both execute c++ code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO: Using G++ to compile multiple .cpp and .h files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202136/7478597)

Comment: And yet another: [SO: Compiling multiple .cpp and .h files using g++. Am I doing it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26814485/7478597)

Comment: source files and header files are different by convention. They have a different function.

Comment: Also related: [SO: What is a “translation unit” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106149/7478597)

Comment: This seems to provide a good overwiew considering also declaration/definition and external/internal linkage: [Internal and External Linkage in C++](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++/)

Comment: I'll have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you #include a file you effectively copy/paste the contents of that file at the line of the include. Therefore, yes, you are including the method test() twice in your program.

You generally only include "header" files. These generally define the signature of the methods. With the body/implementation of the method in the .cpp file.

Comment: I understand everything except for the fact in this case, how I am including it twice? I define it in other.cpp, and include other.cpp in main.cpp. Where is the second definition?

Comment: You have other.cpp "embedded" in your main.cpp and you also add it on the command line when you compile.

Comment: Oh, so I should only compile main.cpp?

Comment: You should never include a .cpp file.

Comment: Yes. That's one way of fixing it.