# Compiling with .o files

Tags: c++

I keep getting a bunch of compile messages when I try and compile a class.

I was wondering if this method I'm using to compile using terminal is correct.

So I have the files a.cpp, aImp.cpp & a.h

I create .o (object) file for aImp.cpp with

```
cc -c aImp.cpp
```

Afterwards

```
cc a.cpp aImp.o
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using G++ to compile multiple .cpp and .h files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files)

Comment: `cc` is the Unix system `C` compiler (`gcc` on Linux), you need `c++` (or `g++` on Linux).

Comment: but I am converting my implementation into a object file. Nothing seems to happen when I use g++ -o ...

Comment: You don't "compile classes" in C++, by the way - you compile files.

Comment: how would i compile a object file with the main file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax

`g++ -Wall aImp.cpp a.cpp -o app`

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought u need g++ for cpp