# Seperate class file program showing error in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I made 3 files in the same directory `lec42.cpp`, `MohitSinghania.cpp` and 
`MohitSinghania.h`.

`MohitSinghania.h`

```
#ifndef MOHITSINGHANIA_H
#define MOHITSINGHANIA_H
class MohitSinghania
{
public:
    MohitSinghania();

    void grtQuotation();          
};

#endif // MOHITSINGHANIA_H
```

`MohitSinghania.cpp`

```
#include "MohitSinghania.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
MohitSinghania::MohitSinghania()
{

}
    void MohitSinghania::grtQuotation(){
    cout<<"Get Up But Don't Give Up!\n";
}
```

`lec42.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "MohitSinghania.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    MohitSinghania ms;
    ms.grtQuotation();

}
```

Now when I compile `lec42.cpp` in cmd then it shows this error:

```
G:\code\pracc++>c++ lec42.cpp
C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccE5vbeE.o:lec42.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `MohitSinghania::MohitSinghania()'
C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccE5vbeE.o:lec42.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `MohitSinghania::grtQuotation()
link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the MohitSinghania.cpp is also not compiling

```
g:\code\pracc++>c++ MohitSinghania.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../..      /../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

,MohitSinghania.h is compiling with instruction

```
c++ MohitSinghania.h
```

Comment: how are you compiling your program? you need to compile all the source files see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files

Comment: You need to compile all *.cpp files. The easiest way to achieve this using g++ would be the command `g++ -o outputFile.exe *.cpp`.

Comment: done but still not working.