# C++, instantiating a generic Node storing an instance of an object using templates

Tags: c++, templates, object, generics, nodes

I am currently attempting to implement a Doubly Linked List for a Data Structures class.

I currently have implemented a generic Node* class and wanted to hold an instance of another class Student(int i, int j) that I have implemented.

This is what i'm attempting to do in my main method:

```
Student student1 = Student(10,11);
Node<Student()> node1 = Node<Student()> (student1);
```

This is the error I am receiving.
Everything worked absolutely fine when the Node was holding a primitive data type like an int but i'm unsure how to account for the difference between storing an int and storing a Student object.

I would love any insight or pushes in the right direction.
Thank you.

[image]

Here is my implementation of Node.

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template <class T>
class Node
{
    public:
    Node();
    Node(T k);
    virtual~Node();

    T key;
    Node<T>* prev;
    Node<T>* next;
};
#endif

//default constructor
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}

 template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T k)
{
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
    key = k;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
//implement 
}
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student()
{
    mArrivalTime = 0;
    mTimeNeeded = 0;
}
Student::Student(int arrivalTime, int timeNeeded)
{
    mArrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    mTimeNeeded = timeNeeded;
}

Student::~Student()
{
     //implement
}

int Student::getArrivalTime()
{
    return mArrivalTime;
}

int Student::getTimeNeeded()
{
    return mTimeNeeded;
}
```

Student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

using namespace std;
class Student
{
    private:
        int mArrivalTime;
        int mTimeNeeded;

     public:
        Student();
        Student(int arrivalTime, int timeNeeded);
        ~Student();
        int getArrivalTime();
        int getTimeNeeded();
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use (), just use the class name. e.g:

```
Node<Student> node1 = Node<Student> (student1);
```

Comment: I was curious as to if this would work, but when I do I receive this error:        Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Student::Student(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Assignment4-1de395.o
  "Student::Student()", referenced from:
      Node<Student>::Node(Student) in Assignment4-1de395.o
  "Student::~Student()", referenced from:
      _main in Assignment4-1de395.o
      Node<Student>::~Node() in Assignment4-1de395.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: That is a linker error, which probably means that the compile step worked. I would guess that you need to add Student.cpp to your `g++` command line, so it is linked in with your main .cpp file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files for more info

Comment: Ahhh, of course. I got so used to working with templates for this assignment and not having to compile header files that I forgot entirely about Student.cpp needing to be compiled. Thank you.