# c++ header files, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to build a program to store student grades in C++. I'm receiving the following error when compiling:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "grade1(Student_records const&)", referenced from:
 _main in gradereport-a0007a.o

 "compare(Student_records const&, Student_records const&)", 

referenced from: _main in gradereport-a0007a.o

"read_info(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Student_records&)", 

referenced from: _main in gradereport-a0007a.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The command I have been (trying) to use to compile: g++ gradereport.cpp

The told me that something about my read_info, compare, and grade1 functions were wrong (improperly defined). But, I cannot seem to find the issue.

From reading through prior posts on "undefined symbols" issues, it seems that either (a) my function declarations do not match or (b) I need to compile multiple files "at the same time" (for lack of a better phrase). I'm pretty sure it is not (a). If (b), how precisely would I accomplish this task? Also, if anybody has any basic criticism, I would love to hear it. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

gradereport.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ios>
#include<iomanip>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stdexcept>
#include "student_records.h"
#include "Grades.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::max;
using std::domain_error;

int main()
{

    vector<Student_records> students; 
    Student_records record; 
    string::size_type maxlen = 0;

    while(read_info(cin, record))
    {

        maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size()); // finds the longest name
        students.push_back(record); // enters each record into the vector

    }

    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare); 
    for(vector<Student_records>::size_type i = 0; i != students.size(); ++i)
    {

        cout << students[i].name
            << string(maxlen + 1 - students[i].name.size(), ' ');

        try
        {

            double final_grade = grade1(students[i]);
            /* need to define grade function:
                1) unpack grades;
                2) find homework grades;
                3) find final grade;
            */
            cout << final_grade

        }

        catch(domain_error e)
        {

            cout << e.what();

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

student_records.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_STUDENT_RECORDS
#define GUARD_STUDENT_RECORDS

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

struct Student_records
{

    std::string name;
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homeworks;

};

bool compare(const Student_records&, const Student_records&);
std::istream& read_info(std::istream&, Student_records&);
std::istream& read_homework(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);

#endif
```

student_records.cpp

```
#include "student_records.h"

bool compare(const Student_records& x, const Student_records& y)
{

    return x.name < y.name;

}

std::istream& read_info(istream& is, Student_records& s)
{

    std::cout << "Enter name, midterm, and final: ";
    is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

    read_homework(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);

    return is;

}

std::istream& read_homework(std::istream& in, std::vector<double>& homework)
{

    cout << "Enter homework: ";

    if(in)
    {
        hw.clear()

        double x;
        while(in >> x)
            homework.push_back(x);

        in.clear();
    }

    return in;

}
```

Grades.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_GRADES
#define GUARD_GRADES

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include "student_records.h"

double grade1(const Student_records&);
double grade2(double, double, std::vector<double>);
double median(std::vector<double>);

#endif
```

Grades.cpp

```
#include<stdexcept>
#include<vector>
#include "grades.h"
#include "Student_records.h"

using std::domain_error;
using std::vector;

double grade2(double midterm, double final, std::vector<double> homework)
{

    double final_homework_grade;

    final_homework_grade = median(homework);

    return .4 * final_homework_grade + .4 * final + .2 * midterm;

}

double median(vector<double> homework)
{

    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;

    vec_sz size = homework.size();

    if(size == 0)
        throw domain_error("student has done no homework");

    sort(homework.begin(), homework.end());

    return size % 2 == 0 ? ((homework[mid] + homework[mid + 1]) / 2) : homework[mid];

}

double grade1(const Student_records& s) // unpacks grades
{

    return grade2(s.midterm, s.final, s.homework);

}
```

Comment: You are only compiling the one file (`gradereport.cpp`) which is missing the functions implemented in `student_records.cpp`. See [Using G++ to compile multiple .cpp and .h files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files)

Comment: Thank you! Hope it works

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been already solved in this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files).

The issue arises because you are not compiling all .cpp or .cc files and hence the compiler fails to recognize the inclusions added by your header file.

I hope this helps somebody.