# c++ inheritance issues: undefined reference to 'vtable'

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, header-files, vtable

all! I am trying to create a very simple inheritance structure using C++ and header files but (of course) I am having some difficulties.

When I try to compile my main program, I get this error:

```
In function `Base::Base()':
undefined reference to 'vtable for Base'
In function `Derived::Derived()':
undefined reference to 'vtable for Derived'
```

All I want is to print is

```
printed in Derived
```

but I am having some extreme difficulties.

Here are my program files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    Base *bp = new Derived;
    bp->show();
    return 0;
}
```

**Base.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"

virtual void Base::show() {
    cout << "printed in Base";
}
```

**Base.h**

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base {
    public:
        virtual void show();
};

#endif
```

**Derived.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Derived.h"

using namespace std;

void Derived::show() override {
    cout << "printed in Derived";
}
```

**Derived.h**

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

class Derived: public Base {
    public:
        void show() override;
};

#endif
```

Thank you! And any help is very much appreciated!...extremely.

Comment: What compiler are you using and how are you compiling?

Comment: I am using g++ on linux terminal

Comment: Ok, you answered half of the question...

Comment: I use "g++ main.cpp"

Comment: So, you haven't compiled the other two files?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the `virtual` and `override` function specifiers belong only in the header file, not the cpp

Comment: You are also missing a virtual destructor and a `delete` at the end (of course, in real code, you'd probably use `std::unique_ptr`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, by calling `g++ main.cpp` you are only compiling `main.cpp`.

You need to compile all files, then link them together. If you do so, you will see that there are compilation issues in your other cpp files as also pointed out in the comments (*virtual and override only belong in the header*).

So you need to call the following to compile all files:

`g++ main.cpp Base.cpp Derived.cpp -o myapp`

Comment: g++ *.cpp -o output and (there were errors) but now it compiles.