# ostream in class does not have a type

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files, ostream, istream

Just got into C++ and I have a quick question.

After compiling with

```
g++ *.cpp -o output
```

I receive this error:

```
error: 'ostream' in 'class Dollar' does not name a type
```

These are my three files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Currency.h"
#include "Dollar.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    Currency *cp = new Dollar;

    // I want this to print "printed in Dollar in overloaded << operator"
    cout << cp;
    return 0;
}
```

**Dollar.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dollar.h"

using namespace std;

void Dollar::show() {
    cout << "printed in Dollar";
}

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Dollar &d) {
    out << "printed in Dollar in overloaded << operator";
}
```

**Dollar.h**

```
#include "Currency.h"

#ifndef DOLLAR_H
#define DOLLAR_H

class Dollar: public Currency {
    public:
        void show();
};

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Dollar &d);

#endif
```

Thank you for your time, and everything helps!

Comment: It is called `std::ostream`.

Comment: Use `std::ostream`. Don't use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: So delete    using namespace std    in my Dollar.cpp file?

Comment: and add std:ostream to both my .cpp and .h files?

Comment: Chances are that compilation string will not work either. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files) SO post on the subject.

Comment: Unrelated: it is usually best to place all of the header inside the header's include guard. In Dollar.h I recommend moving `#include "Currency.h"` to after `#define DOLLAR_H`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a number of errors in the code.

1. You heavily use `using namespace std`. [This is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). In particular, this led to the error you faced: you don't have `using namespace std` in `Dollar.h`, thus the compiler has no idea what `ostream` means. Either put `using namespace std` in `Dollar.h` too, or better just stop using it and specify the `std` namespace directly, as in `std::ostream`.
2. You use `std::ostream` in your headers, but you don't include the corresponding standard library header `<ostream>` in them (`<ostream>` contains the definition of `std::ostream` class; for the full I/O library include `<iostream>`). A really good practice is to include all the dependencies of the header in the header itself, so that it is self-contained and can be safely included anywhere.
3. You are implementing a stream output operator with signature `std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, Dollar const &)`, which is perfectly valid. However, you call it for a *pointer* to type `Dollar`. You should rather call it with the *object* itself, not the pointer, so you should dereference the pointer: `std::cout << *cp;`.
4. You implemented the output operator for the `Dollar` class, but use it for a variable of type `Currency`: this won't work. There is a way to do this - there do exist virtual methods for this exact reason. However, in this case the operator is a free function, thus it cannot be virtual. So, you should probably add a virtual `print` method to your `Currency` class, implement it in `Dollar`, and call it from output operator:

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   class Currency {
   public:
       virtual void print (std::ostream &) const = 0;
   };

   class Dollar : public Currency {
       void print (std::ostream & out) const override {
           out << "A dollar";
       }
   };

   std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, Currency const & c) {
       c.print(out);
       return out;
   }

   int main(/* void is redundant here */) {
       Currency *cp = new Dollar;
       std::cout << *cp;
       // return 0 is redundant in main
   }
   ```

Comment: _"You use std::ostream in your headers, but you don't include the corresponding standard library header <iostream> "_ -- The corresponding standard header is `<ostream>`. No need to pull in the full IO stream library.

Comment: @zett42 You are right, thank you! I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include <iostream>` within Dollar.h so that your `std::ostream & operator` is resolved by the compiler.

Comment: In the code shown that isn't actually necessary. But OP *does* need to call it `std::ostream`.

Comment: @juanchopanza why are you saying so? I see no evidence of that.

Comment: @SergeyA it relies on `iostream` being included in `main.cpp` and `Dollar.cpp` before `Dollar.h`. Note that I am not saying the include shouldn't be added, but in this case it isn't the source of the error.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes you are right, missed that order of includes in `main`.