# Why do I get linker command fail error in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I'm having trouble solving a linker error in my code. I do not understand why do I get this. I tried to rewrite it, make the same parameters, but nothing changed. Any idea?

main.cpp

```
int first_max(const string &name, Champship& e)
{

    ChampshipEnor t(name);
    bool l = false;
    int _max   = -1;
    while(!t.end()){
        if(!t.current().isHigh == true){

        }else if (l){
            if(t.current().point > _max){
                _max = t.current().point;
                e    = t.current();
            }
        }else{
            l = true;
            _max = t.current().point;
            e    = t.current();
        }
    }
    return _max;
}



int main(){

    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter the name of the input file, please:"; cin>>filename;

    //First task
    cout<<"First  task\n";
    try{
        Champship e;
        if(first_max(filename, e)){
            cout<<e.racer<<" has scored the most point ("<<e.point<<") in "<<e.year<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"There is no racer matching our search criteria.\n";
        }
    }catch(ChampshipEnor::FileError err)
    {
        cerr<<"Can't find the input file:"<<filename<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

champship.h

```
//#pragma once

//#include <fstream>
//#include <sstream>
//#include <string>



struct Champship {
    std::string racer;
    int year;
    int point;
    bool isHigh = false;

};

class ChampshipEnor{

    private:
        std::ifstream _f;
        Champship _cur;
        bool _end;
    public:
        enum FileError{MissingInputFile};
        ChampshipEnor(const std::string &str) throw (FileError);
        void first() {next();}
        void next();
        Champship current() const { return _cur;}
        bool end() const { return _end;}
};
```

champship.cpp

```
#include "champship.h"

ChampshipEnor::ChampshipEnor(const std::string &str) throw (FileError)
{
    _f.open(str);
    if(_f.fail())throw MissingInputFile;
}

void ChampshipEnor::next()
{
    std::string line;
    getline(_f , line);
    if( !(_end = _f.fail()) ){
        istringstream is(line);
        is >> _cur.racer >> _cur.year;
        _cur.point = 0;
        std::string category;
        int pos;
        for( is >> category >> pos ; !is.fail(); is >> category >> pos ){
            if(category == "magasugras"){
                _cur.isHigh = true;
                }

            switch(pos) {

                case 1 :
                    _cur.point += 12;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    _cur.point += 10;
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    _cur.point += 8;
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    _cur.point += 6;
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    _cur.point += 4;
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    _cur.point += 2;
                    break;

            }
        }
        //if (_cur.high == true && _cur.point > _max) _max = _cur.point;
    }
}
```

The linker error, what I get when I build the code:

g++  -o "/Volumes/1TB HDD/Coding/op/masodikbead/main" "/Volumes/1TB HDD/Coding/op/masodikbead/main.o"
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ChampshipEnor::ChampshipEnor(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
      first_max(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, Champship&) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Checking for existence: /Volumes/1TB HDD/Coding/op/masodikbead/main

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the code something like this:

`g++ "path to your main.cpp" "path to your champship.cpp" -o a.out`

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files) question.

You can also refer [this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/programs-with-multiple-code-files/) article.

Remember, you have to include all the `.cpp` files (if your are using) during the compilation. In your case, you are using `ChampshipEnor` object, in your main function and the class is defined in `champship.cpp`.