# How do I create a C++ program with each class in a different file

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I want to create a class say PEN in one one c++ file and inherit it in another class that is in a separate file and finally run the program from a C++ file that has only the main function. I know this is a basic thing but I am new to C++. The program is a console program.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? How are you intending to build the project? Are you for example using CMake or Visualstudio?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things here.

. Referencing
. Compling
. Linking

1. Referencing
   You put your classes and main function in separate .cpp files.
   Each file that references a class in another file needs to #include class.h where class.h is the headers that include the class declarations. You can have a single shared header for all the files, or a separate one for each. Usually there is a .h for each .cpp with the same name by convention.
2. Compiling
   Then when you complie, you need to decide if you want a single binary blob (for you, this is my recommendation) or a library to link to.
   Not sure exactly the cpp compile options but it will be something like: path/to/cpp-compiler main.cpp class.cpp
   Order is important here, the classes main.cpp needs must be specified AFTER main.cpp on the command line.
3. Linking
   If you chose to compile a separate library, you will need to do:
   path/to/cpp-compiler 
   -c class.cpp
   path/to/cpp-compiler -c main.cpp
   separately, then do:
   path/to/cpp-compiler -o a.out main.cpp class.o
   to link.
   You can also pack multiple .o files into a .so or dll if you like and link to that.
   Linking can become quite complex and has many quirks so I think stick with compiling all you sources together for now until you get more familiar with it.

This is a good answer here: [Using G++ to compile multiple .cpp and .h files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files)

I suggest you do a little more research as there are bound to be heaps of other answers to this question.