# VSCode - C++ - Problem with MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

[There is photo of files included in this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STrMq.png)

Some time ago I started learning object programming in C++ in VSCode. I decided to create quiz using three files - main.cpp, pytanie.h, pytanie.cpp. I wrote all the code which was necessary. My problem is that when I want to start debugging it shows me communique like that:

[The statement which VSCode shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV5tI.png)

For addition maybe it will help, I'm gonna paste code form main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pytanie.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Pytanie p1;
p1.nr_pytania = 1;
p1.wczytaj();
p1.zadaj();
p1.sprawdz();

cout << "KONIEC QUIZU! PUNKTY = " << p1.punkt;

return 0;
}
```

[There's file pytanie.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hjaT.png)

Comment: instead of `g++ main.cpp` you need to compile all the .cpp files in your project

Comment: This is in the documentation for vscode here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: VSCode can be a pain to beat into submission. This may change in a few years and a few more iterations of VSCode, but for now if you're learning C++ you probably don't also want to be learning how to wrangle your build tools. See if you can use a community edition of Visual Studio or something with simpler C++ integration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `g++ main.cpp` on PS, you should run : `g++ main.cpp pytanie.cpp`.

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files) for more information.

One thing I would like to add is don’t write namespace usings in a header file. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers).

Also I would recommend you to follow [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) to setup `tasks.json` in your workspace. It can save your typing! :)