# Usage of header files

Tags: c++

I have received the following code that is only supposed to allow the allocation of a string-variable in the class constructor.
I have tried many things but always get the following error:

"undefined reference to 'Patient::Patient(std::string)"

**Patient.hpp**

```
#ifndef Patient_hpp
#define Patient_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Patient{
protected:
    string name;

public:
    Patient(string name);
};
#endif // Patient_hpp
```

**Patient.cpp**

```
#include "Patient.hpp"

Patient::Patient(string name){
    this->name=name;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Patient.hpp"


int main(){
    Patient p("Mary");

    return 0;
}
```

I would be very grateful for your help.

Best regards

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need to compile and link `Main.cpp` with `Paitent.cpp`.  If you are using g++, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files

Comment: Likely your problem is you are not building `Patient.cpp`. If you are using VSCode remember the default behavior of this code editor to build only the active file into the executable. You have to use the change in the documentation on how to modify tasks.json to fix that.

Comment: Mhm I understand that your suggestion is that the main file does not compile the Patient.cpp-file as well. However, I compile my file via Code::Blocks. I really don't understand how I would approach this as the references are using g++ to my understanding.

Comment: in Code::Blocks perhaps you did not add `Patient.cpp` to your project. Being in the same folder as `Main.cpp` does not help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know if I would have ever thought about this without your help. Very much appreciated