# How to compile multiple files with g++

Tags: c++, g++

I want to know if there is a way to compile a lot of *.cpp files at once with a g++ command. The way I know to do it is to just type the name of every file manually. That gets a little complicated when I have a big project.
I am using g++ version 6.3.0 on windows.

Comment: You probably want to use a build system, e.g. GNU make.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your quesiton can be found here [Using G++ to compile multiple .cpp and .h files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files).

To put it simple the solution would be as explained in that post.

`g++ main.cpp other.cpp etc.cpp`

Also to automate that kind of stuff i would suggest that you look into Makefiles. A simple guide can be found here: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/cpp-makefile-tutorial/

Comment: That is the solution I knew about. But thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Kabajat2008 i edited it. Maybe makefiles could be intersting for you then.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it.